# Cannot save the attachment. The operation failed. An object cannot be found error in server

Tags: c#, outlook, attachment

I am trying of save attachment of outlook mail, i am able to save attachment when it have data. but for empty attachment its throws exception that `Cannot save the attachment. The operation failed. An object cannot be found`.
In my local i am able to save but this issue is coming in server.

`void saveattachments(Outlook.Attachment attachment)
{
string currentTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh_MM_ss");
try
{
attachment.SaveAsFile(GetConfigSettings("attachmentPath") + "\\attachment_" + "_" + currentTime + "_" + attachment.FileName);
}
catch(exception e)
{}
}`

why it throws error in server for blank file but not in local.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution. Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office?wa=wsignin1.0%3Fwa%3Dwsignin1.0) article.

You may consider using MAPI instead (a low-level API on which Outlook is based on).